# How to make a button Visible when RecyclerView has items in it?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, visibility

i'm making a note taking app. 
There's a button to clear all the items in RecyclerView and its Visibility is set to Gone. But I want it to be Visible only when there are Notes in the app.
 I don't know why using
 if (notesList.size()>0){
            removeAllButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 doesn't work! How can i do this? 
 Edit: Added the Adapter code.
Here's my Main Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<Notes> notesList = new ArrayList<>();
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1001;
final NoteAdapter adapter = new NoteAdapter(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Button addNoteButton = findViewById(R.id.button_main_addNote);
    final Button removeAllButton = findViewById(R.id.button_main_deleteAll);
    addNoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoteEdit.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });


    removeAllButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.removeAll();
            removeAllButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    if (adapter.getItemCount()>=1){
        removeAllButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE &&
            resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
            data != null) {
        String noteTitle = data.getStringExtra(NoteEdit.Result_Key_Title);
        String noteDescription = data.getStringExtra(NoteEdit.Result_Key_Description);
        Notes notes = new Notes();
        notes.setNoteTitle(noteTitle);
        notes.setNoteDescription(noteDescription);
        adapter.addNote(notes);
        adapter.getItemCount();
    }
}}
```

Adapter Class :

```
public class NoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.SimpleItemViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Notes> notes = new ArrayList<>();

public NoteAdapter(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public SimpleItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_sample, parent, false);
    return new SimpleItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindNote(notes.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return notes.size();
}

public void addNote(Notes note) {
    notes.add(note);
    notifyItemInserted(notes.size() - 1);
}

public void removeAll () {
    notes.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private TextView titleTextView;
private TextView descriptionTextView;

public class SimpleItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public SimpleItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        titleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemSample_title);
        descriptionTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemSample_description);
    }


    public void bindNote(Notes note) {
        titleTextView.setText(note.getNoteTitle());
        descriptionTextView.setText(note.getNoteDescription());
    }

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your Code, You should try with [**`getItemCount()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemCount())

> Returns the total number of items in the data set held by the
>   adapter.

```
  if(adapter.getItemCount() != 0)
    {
    // VISIBLE
    }
```

Comment: I did the same thing before asking here but surprisingly it doesn't work and the button stays Gone no matter if there are items in the app or not!
I'll add the Adapter codes to the Question. take a look if there's something wrong there

Comment: @Hamed nope, where you add values respect to `notesList` . You did `adapter.addNote(notes);`

Comment: @Hamed `if(adapter.getItemCount() != 0)
    {
    // VISIBLE
    }`

Comment: @IntelliJ-Amiliya None of them worked :/ 
the button stays Gone

Comment: @Hamed `if (adapter.getItemCount()>0)`

Comment: @Hamed Solved this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I see that in onActivityResult you actually add the notes to the RecyclerView by using your adapter. After adding the note to the adapter you probably call notifydatasetchanged from the adapter.
After adding the note in the activity call getItemCount() on the adapter and only if it equal one make the button visible.
On the clicklistener of remove all button you should hide the button.

Also change notifyitemInserted after addnote to notifydatasetchanged

Gili

```
    package com.example.gilad.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Notes> notesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1001;
    final NoteAdapter adapter = new NoteAdapter(this);
    private View mRemoveAllButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Button addNoteButton = findViewById(R.id.button_main_addNote);
        mRemoveAllButton = findViewById(R.id.button_main_deleteAll);
        addNoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoteEdit.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });


        mRemoveAllButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.removeAll();
                mRemoveAllButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE &&
                resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
                data != null) {
            String noteTitle = data.getStringExtra(NoteEdit.Result_Key_Title);
            String noteDescription = data.getStringExtra(NoteEdit.Result_Key_Description);
            Notes notes = new Notes();
            notes.setNoteTitle(noteTitle);
            notes.setNoteDescription(noteDescription);
            adapter.addNote(notes);
            final int adapterCount = adapter.getItemCount();
            if (adapterCount == 1){
                mRemoveAllButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }}
```

Comment: I did as you said. but didn't work :/
Only the button becomes Gone after being clicked

Comment: I've add the code. hope it will help you.
Please note that I've changed the remove all button to a memeber.